# flask admin edit child objects on click

Tags: python, relationship, flask-admin

Flask-Admin shows child objects defined by relationships in its standard edit view. For example, if `User` objects have `Address` children, looking at the edit view for `User` will show the `Address` child in the appropriate field. The user can then remove the object, or add another one.

I want users to be able to click through, or otherwise have the ability to enter the edit view of child objects. In the example I'm describing, the user should be able to access the edit view of the `Address` object directly from the edit view of the `User` object.

The only thing I've found at all related is `inline_models`, but this isn't a solution. The implementation is extremely fragile (it can't handle long distance relationships, for example). Flask-Admin is aware of child objects! I can see them in the view! I just want them to become a link to their own edit view...

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this or can link to an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a single file simple example of placing a link to another model's edit view in an edit view. It may help you or not.

[image]

I've used a User - Address relationship, a user has an address and address can have many users.

I've used [Faker](http://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to generate sample data so you'll need to `pip install faker` into your environment.

The idea is to use Flask-Admin [form rules](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_form_rules) and in this case I'm configuring `form_edit_rules`.

I've created two custom rules:

`Link`, inheriting `BaseRule`. The constructor takes three values; an endpoint, a name of an attribute to pass along with the endpoint in the Flask `url_for` method and finally the text to appear as the link. In this example the endpoint is `'address.edit_view'` because this is the view we want to link to.

`MultiLink`, similar to `Link` accepts it works with a relation.

Here's the code (there's little error checking):

```
from random import randint
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.form.rules import BaseRule
from faker import Faker
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from markupsafe import Markup
from sqlalchemy import func, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

fake = Faker()

# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'

# Create in-memory database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


class Address(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    number = db.Column(db.String(255))
    street = db.Column(db.String(255))
    city = db.Column(db.String(255))
    country = db.Column(db.String(255))

    @hybrid_property
    def user_count(self):
        return len(self.users)

    @user_count.expression
    def user_count(cls):
        return select([func.count(User.id)]).where(User.address_id == cls.id).label("user_count")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ', '.join(filter(None, [self.number, self.street, self.city, self.country]))


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(254))

    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('addresses.id'), index=True)
    address = db.relationship(Address, backref=db.backref('users'))

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Link(BaseRule):
    def __init__(self, endpoint, attribute, text):
        super(Link, self).__init__()
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.text = text
        self.attribute = attribute

    def __call__(self, form, form_opts=None, field_args=None):
        if not field_args
            field_args = {}

        _id = getattr(form._obj, self.attribute, None)

        if _id:
            return Markup('<a href="{url}">{text}</a>'.format(url=url_for(self.endpoint, id=_id), text=self.text))


class MultiLink(BaseRule):
    def __init__(self, endpoint, relation, attribute):
        super(MultiLink, self).__init__()
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.relation = relation
        self.attribute = attribute

    def __call__(self, form, form_opts=None, field_args=None):
        if not field_args
            field_args = {}
        _hrefs = []
        _objects = getattr(form._obj, self.relation)
        for _obj in _objects:
            _id = getattr(_obj, self.attribute, None)
            _link = '<a href="{url}">Edit {text}</a>'.format(url=url_for(self.endpoint, id=_id), text=str(_obj))
            _hrefs.append(_link)

        return Markup('<br>'.join(_hrefs))


class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    can_view_details = True

    form_edit_rules = (
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'address',
        Link(endpoint='address.edit_view', attribute='address_id', text='Edit Address')
    )


class AddressAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    can_view_details = True

    column_list = ['number', 'street', 'city', 'country', 'user_count', 'users']

    form_edit_rules = (
        'number',
        'street',
        'city',
        'country',
        'users',
        MultiLink(endpoint='user.edit_view', relation='users', attribute='id')
    )


admin = Admin(app, template_mode="bootstrap3")
admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(AddressAdmin(Address, db.session))


def build_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    for _ in range(0, 20):
        _users = []
        for _ in range(0, randint(1, 10)):
            _user = User(
                first_name=fake.first_name(),
                last_name=fake.last_name(),
                email=fake.safe_email(),
            )
            _users.append(_user)

        _address = Address(
            number=fake.random_digit_not_null(),
            street=fake.secondary_address(),
            city=fake.city(),
            country=fake.country(),
            users = _users
        )

        db.session.add(_address)

    db.session.commit()


@app.before_first_request
def first_request():
    build_db()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Would you be able to update this to describe how to deal with collections of children? For example, if users could have multiple addresses?

Comment: @melchoir55 - I've added a `MultiLink` form rule that works with a relation.

Comment: First off, thank you, exactly what I needed.  But in your address drop down on the user view, how did you get it to show the actual address, mine just says <Address 1>

Comment: @brickfungus - have you defined a `__str__` method for your Address class ?

Comment: @pjcunningham yes, but I spelled it __string__ like an idiot... THANK YOU! Works now